# Regex to remove spacing between paragraphs (find and replace)

Tags: google-docs

I work with scripts that are split into many paragraphs. I need to find a way to turn this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.

Et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim. Ad minim veniam.
```

into this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim. Ad minim veniam.
```

I want to use 'Find and replace' with regex. I'm trying different combinations of \s, \n tags and dot with escaping character and I can usually fix the text in 2-3 iterations with some manual tweaks but I think there should be a regex that would do the job at once. Can you think of something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex pattern to achieve the desired result in a 'Find and replace' operation:

Find:

```
(\S)\s*\n\s*(\S)
```

Replace:

```
$1 $2
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Do I need to swap $1 $2 for something? Otherwise it just inserts these characters wherever there was a space/line break before, cutting the first letter of each sentence.

Comment: Okay, as far as I understand, try replacing the string with ([^\s])\s*\n\s*([^\s]) and try again.

Comment: you can't use regex in 'replace' field it seems, only in 'find'.

Comment: Yes I know, you need to add regex in FIND only. Keep the REPLACE same.

Comment: ah, gotcha. It doesn't work I'm afraid, it missed almost all line brakes and spaces.

Comment: Uh huh. Wait. Try couple of things => 1st : Find:  (?<=\n\n)([^\n]+)\n\n Replace:  $1

Comment: Also can you define all the usecase you are testing?

Comment: The last script replaces most of the text with $1$1$1... Something wrong I'm doing that it's just pasting $1 everywhere?

As for use cases, it's quite simple. I have video scripts that have 1-4 sentences in each paragraph and there are dozens of paragraphs. Here's a sample script I want to format: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q5c4eM5DUvZxDQb1bPg8vJn8CE_M4lt4I6Bed21RzI8/edit?usp=sharing, you can edit it if you want. With several iterations and some manual work I already managed to convert it into the desired format (see it below in that file) but Iit required too much time and clicking

Comment: Use case - i feed the formatted scripts to YT and it turns them into subtitles without any awkward line breaks, additional characters etc